# Replace multiple lines with value in line.

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

```
> OTHER CODES
> OTHER CODES 
Want to remove this line>' {
Want to remove this line but keep Bob >id : 1 / @gateway="local" / @name="Bob / @views="500"
Want to remove this line>sample : 1
Want to remove this line>cash : 500
Want to remove this line>bets : 1
> OTHER CODES
> OTHER CODES
> OTHER CODES
> OTHER CODES
> OTHER CODES
```

Hello I have about 500 lines of code that looks like above. What I aim to do is the following remove all the lines except for @name="Bob" but also keep my "Other Codes". Is there a way to do this with grep + awk ?

Currently I can use

```
grep -A 1 -B 3 "@name" ok
```

to grab all the lines I want. The name can change base on the user. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How should the result look like?

Comment: I agree with the other people who have commented, the question is not clear. It would be much more useful if you showed the desired output separately.

Comment: Funny Avinash got it ...  I thought it was pretty clear . I want to remove the lines I ask "Want to remove this line ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
$ grep -oP '@name=\S+|^>.*' file
> OTHER CODES
> OTHER CODES
@name="Bob
> OTHER CODES
> OTHER CODES
> OTHER CODES
> OTHER CODES
> OTHER CODES
```